# passing variables to a multi-threaded sub in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, parameter-passing

I am hoping someone might be able to help me, I am trying to do some multi-threading of my application which is a vb.net console which works on recieved serial data and processes it accordingly.

I have a number of subs, which are worth multi-threading (e.g. writing to MySQL) but my biggest issue is around my understanding of multi-threading and passing parameters.

In my system, i receive serial data and parse it to obtain a string variable "fixed" which may change on a very fast basis.

```
        If fixed <> "" Then
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString & "  " & fixed)
            Console.WriteLine("")
            PageProcessing.DoWork(fixed)
        End If
```

from what I understand something like system.threading.thread would be worth looking at, like the example below:

```
Dim MessageThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf PageProcessing.DoWork)
        MessageThread.Start()
```

Where i am confused though is how I can pass the fixed variable to that sub, if I have it as a global variable, there is every possibility the variable will change and make it pointless, but as I understand it I can't directly pass it through the thread, but is there another way I can achieve this?

I use this as an example, but if I can pass a variable / object / class through then I would use the same concept and apply that to other subs.

Many thanks in Advance!

Comment: You can send a parameter to the [Start method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO the simplest way is to use a lambda expression to define the sub or function to use for your thread which allows the argument to be passed to it directly:

```
    Dim MessageThread As New System.Threading.Thread(Sub() PageProcessing.DoWork(fixed))
    MessageThread.Start()
```

Alternatively you can use an overload of the Start method to pass a parameter but this is not the preferred method as is not type safe as it only accepts an Object type. It is also not that efficient for value types as they will be boxed and unboxed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it is most appreciated!